# How can I return true if my cursor is pressed while in a box and not pressed and then dragged in?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, mouseevent

I have a box in pygame and I want to print some text to the console if the mouse button is pressed while the cursor is inside the box. The problem is I don't want the text to print if the mouse button is pressed and then dragged into the box.

I have tried:

```
if mousePos[0] >= 500 and mousePos[0] <= 530 and mousePos[1] >= 0 and mousePos[1] <= 100 and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
    scrollButtonColour = (25,25,25)
    print(mousePos)
else:
    scrollButtonColour = (50,50,50)
```

Cheers.

Edit:

Here is the full code for testing (I made slight changes since posting question):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Scroll Bar")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

FPS = 60

gameExit = False

scrollButtonColour = (50,50,50)


while not gameExit:

    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    scrollButtonColour = (50,50,50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True


    if mousePos[0] >= 500 and mousePos[0] <= 530 and mousePos[1] >= 0 and mousePos[1] <= 100:
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            scrollButtonColour = (25,25,25)
            print(mousePos)




    gameDisplay.fill(green)

    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (200,200,100,100))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, scrollButtonColour, (500, 0, 30, 100))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Unrelated side note: Python programmers usually use "snake_case" for variable names instead of "camelCase". [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that the event is only printed if the player clicks inside the 
box and not releasing the mouse after the player dragged the mouse into the object
you can use `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`.

This way you can check if the mouse is actually pressed. If you do this after 
you have checked that your mouse position is inside the object, drags into the 
object will not be printed, only clicks inside of the object.

This is how the code would look like :

```
if mousePos[0] >= 500 and mousePos[0] <= 530 and mousePos[1] >= 0 and mousePos[1] <= 100:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
            scrollButtonColour = (25,25,25)
            print(mousePos)
```

To make this code work you will have to put this code into the loop where you check for events

Answer (score 0):

I'd first check if the mouse button was pressed, then if the button rect collides with the mouse pos, change the color of the button and print the text. When the button is released you can reset the color. I've got an example that also shows you how to use a pygame.Rect and its collidepoint method. Since mouse events have a `pos` attribute, you can use this instead of calling `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`.

```
import sys
import pygame


pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Rect(x_pos, y_pos, width, height)
scrollButton = pygame.Rect(500, 0, 30, 100)
scrollButtonColour = (50, 50, 50)

gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if scrollButton.collidepoint(event.pos):
                scrollButtonColour = (25, 25, 25)
                print(event.pos)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            scrollButtonColour = (50, 50, 50)

    gameDisplay.fill((0, 255, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, scrollButtonColour, scrollButton)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

If you want to make more buttons or other GUI elements, it would be a good idea to define classes for them. Put the instances into a list or sprite group and in the event loop pass the events to the instances to handle them.